# switch from PHP to Ruby Rails / Android Develpment / Objective C

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, windows-mobile, mobile-phones

I am a PHP programmers and want to try my hands in something new. I am interested in mobile application development. But confused which platform is best for me.

- Ruby on Rails
- Objective C
- Sencha / Jtouch
- Android Development
- Windows 7 Mobile

Ruby on Rails seems interesting as far as I researched.

Please kindly share ideas in this with resources available, difficulties to learn, pros/cons, scope in current market etc....

Thank you in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your keen interest in learning new platform. Good to know. You have specified various languages but you have not mentioned your specific section. There are 2 section in mobile where you can put your hands on,

- Server side
- Mobile native apps

In server side you focus on providing data to native apps and for this, you can use PHP,ruby on rails, python, CFM and many other server script.

The choice for your language on native apps development depends upon the smart phone you choose. For instance if its iphone you need to go for objective C. If you wish to develop smartphone web applcation you can choose Sencha / Jtouch framework.

To develop for Android phone, you need to learn java,

To develop application for windows 7 mobile you need to learn .net platform.

So just be specific what you wish to develop so that developers at SO, could help you to learn.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.

I am more interested in developing server side application for iphone. But objective C seems complicated and I need MAC for this. Any alternative / easy / fast track for this ???

Comment: If you wish to develope server side application for iphone , then you can go with ruby on rails, python using django framework, you can also use PHP. Your server side application should be able to handle webservice and other server feature that the iphone native apps may require.